# Are long variable names a waste of memory?

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic, coding-style

If I have an variable `int d; //  some comment`. 
Will that be better than `int daysElapsedSinceBlahBlahBlahBlah` with no comment.
It is more reabale, but will it waste memory?

Comment: This will likely solicit discussion. It's not about a specific programming problem you're facing or how to approach it. Not a good fit for SO in my opinion. Also, it highly depends on context.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum The programming problem (at least hypothetical) is stated clearly. Context dependency should be part of the answer

Comment: @icepack It is a matter of preference, this question is open ended.

Comment: It is more readable? - subjective. Will it waste memory? - depends on context / specific implementation, but **"no"**.

Comment: Even if it would waste memory, this memory is cheaper than the time that you or anybody else will waste if you try to read and understand the code you wrote. You can't put a comment on every occurance of every variable (no, please don't try to prove me wrong)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends entirely on the language and its implementation, but I can give you some examples based on a few languages that I know.

In C and C++, variable names are symbolic identifiers for the programmer and compiler. The compiler replaces them with memory addresses, CPU registers, or otherwise inlines their accesses to eliminate them entirely. The names do not appear in the generated code. They can appear in generated debug information, but you can omit that for release builds of a program when you don't need to do interactive step-debugging any more.

In Java, the compiler eliminates function-local variable names and rewrites the code to use stack-relative offsets. Field names (i.e., variables at class level) do persist in the compiled bytecode. This is required mainly because of the way classes are compiled individually and can be linked dynamically at run time, so the compiler cannot optimize the state of the entire program at once. The other reason field names are kept is because they are available through [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29). At run time, the virtual machine can generate native code which largely just uses memory addresses and native CPU registers in the manner of C & C++. Field names are kept in memory anyway, for reflection, and so that any additional loaded classes can be linked in. Mid-stage whole-program optimizers & obfuscators like [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) can make all symbolic names much shorter though.

In languages with an [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/eval) function, such as JavaScript and PHP, even local variable names have to be kept around, in theory, as they can all be accessed by name via run-time strings. A good interpreter can optimize this to use fast memory addresses in cases when it can prove that a particular variable isn't accessed by name.

In true line-by-line interpreters, like very old implementations of [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC), variable names have to be kept around always, because the interpreter operates directly from the source code. It forgets about each line when it moves on to the next, so it has no way to track variables except by their names in the source. Since the full source code had to be kept in memory at run time, and it was often limited to 64 kB or less, variable names really did matter! Code from this era often used (and re-used) cryptically short names because of that (but also for other reasons, such as the way BASIC code was sometimes printed in magazines to be typed in, and these platforms did not have particularly nice keyboards or editors.)

Unless you're programming for an interpreter from the 1980s or earlier, identifier names are so cheap in any case, that you should not worry about it. Chose names that are long enough to be understandable, and short enough to be quick to read. Let the compiler worry about the rest, or run an optimizer or [minifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minifier) on the code after it's written.

Answer (score 8):

You marked this as `language-agnostic` but the example corresponds to C-languages family. In C-like languages the name of the variable shouldn't waste memory, it's just a label for the compiler. In the resulting binary code it will be replaced by a memory address.

In general, there is no benefit in storing the name of variable inside resulting binary, the only usages I can think of is some extreme debug, reverse-engineering or some weird form of reflection. None of these are normal use-cases.

Answer (score 6):

Variable names *never* take up memory. At least not nearly enough to even start worrying about it. While some language implementation will store the variable names *somewhere* (sometimes the language even requires this), the space they take up is absolutely tiny compared to everything else that's flying around. Just use whatever is best by other metrics (readability, conventions, etc.).